# Exploiting WordPress Core Functionality for Development

Tags: wp-load.php

As WordPress is one of the Most Popular platform for the development, I searched and read 100s of articles to understand that if I can harness the power of wordpress *(Like its security and db class)*. There are ways to use **wp-load.php** but not very convincing. What I want to achieve and I am concerned about are-

1. Being famous, wordpress's architecture is well known (Like going through */wp-login.php* one knows the door to login to backend. My new website had ~3000 total hits but got 100+ hits on seeking wp-login.php)
2. I want to get rid of **wp-** terminology for folders and content placement (Like *wp-login/wp-admin/wp-content*). Is there a way **without using plugin** or hampering core?
3. Is there any way to impose your own database structure using power of wordpress. (Although wordpress way of optimising DB is great but sometimes we need few little things)
4. Will it be a good practice to exploit wordpress core file in own web app (Like using **wp-load.php** standalone?) and what could be consequences in terms of security and performance.

Thanks Stack... You make web a better place...

Comment: I think you should consider WordPress as secure or inspect the code to find possible vulnerabilities and report them to get them fixed (which typically doesn't take very long). Anything that goes into the direction of «security by obscurity» (hiding WP) is not worth the effort and I'm in doubt that it is even possible. You can improve security be enforce strong passwords and using a provider that is able to block brute force attacks. But the most important thing is to keep every software up to date.

Comment: That is like fighting the attack. I am also trying to find ways to misguide bots. :/

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu Run your site through Cloudflare  and use their firewall. I've found that really helps cut down on bots sniffing around. And I agree with David, security through obscurity, especially with WP, isn't really worth it.